# multi valued attribute as primary key

Tags: database-design, primary-key

I am designing a database system for my current project and got this situation.
I am having a functional dependency as

> D -> E

Here D is multi valued attribute. D can be(i,j,k) or (i,j) or any other combination. And Unique combination of D will define unique value of E. So i am interested in knowing what is the best way of achieving this requirement.

Comment: Do you mean you want `INSERT INTO d (i,j,k) VALUES (1,2,3), (3,2,1);` to reject because of a constraint violation?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you can have multi-value primary keys. But `PRIMARY KEY` means all values in the composite key are `NOT NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE d ( i int, j int, k int, PRIMARY KEY (i,j,k) );

INSERT INTO d (i,j,k) VALUES (1,2,null);
ERROR:  null value in column "k" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2, null).
```

So, you must be unique on (i,j,k). That makes sense. This can provide a linear map to `E` in your example

> Here D is multi valued attribute. D can be(i,j,k) **or (i,j) or any other combination.**

That's where you've lost me. That doesn't make sense. If they're all `NOT NULL` the only combination that matters is `(i,j,k)`

If you want them such that reordering is also not allowed, for instance. Such that these are rejected..

```
INSERT INTO d (i,j,k) VALUES (1,2,3), (3,2,1);
INSERT INTO d (i,j,k) VALUES (1,2,3), (2,1,3);
```

We can do that too using an [`EXCLUDE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) and [`sort`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) with an array.

```
CREATE TABLE d (
  i int,
  j int,
  k int,
  PRIMARY KEY (i,j,k),
  EXCLUDE (sort(ARRAY[i,j,k]) WITH =)
);
```

Now we get our error.

```
INSERT INTO d (i,j,k) VALUES (1,2,3), (3,2,1);
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "d_sort_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (sort(ARRAY[i, j, k]))=({1,2,3}) conflicts with existing key (sort(ARRAY[i, j, k]))=({1,2,3}).
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot to mention the *requirement* itself.

Multivalued attributes cannot work as primary keys. Actually, multivalued attributes violate [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). So the good idea is to create a separate table and push multivalued attribute into it. Use fictional primary key (i.e. an integer number) for your main table and link each set of D values to the necessary record.

Look [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=hobbies.php) for the example.

BTW, if any *unique* combination of D will define *unique* value of E, you can use E as primary key.

Comment: Why do composite keys violate First Normal Form? Can you elaborate on why you think this is the case?

Comment: @joanolo they say *"multivalued attributes"*, not composite keys. Usually multivalued attributes refers to more than one values stored in the same column. That said, the suggestion after that completely ignores composite keys and makes little sense.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I am not sure this is what the OP meant... (although I agree with you, that's the term s/he used)